# How to have a:hover effects expand past margins?

Tags: css, hover

I have some text links inside a list, then within two divs. I want the hover effects to expand past the list to the outside of the outer div. Is there a way to do it with negative padding? Another way? Possible at all?

Visuals will be easier

How it is now- [image]

Highlight of the padding in the surrounding div- [image]

How I want the a:hover effect to look- [image]

Basically the code looks like this-

```
.1 { padding: 10px;}
.2 { padding: 5px;}

<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>abcde</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>fghij</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code "looks" like this or "is" like this?? It's a bit unclear as to how exactly your code is structured. Did you try `ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}` and test it out?

Answer (score 1):

Negative margin/padding are invalid and don't work as expect,
but is possible, you have to take out all his 
parents margins and add padding to the links to get
the same effect but with all wide anchors:

```
/* CSS CODE */ 
.parent { padding:0px; border:1px solid red }
.child { padding:0px; }
.parent h2 { margin:10px; font-size:22px; }
.child ul li a { display:block; padding:10px 15px; }
.child ul li a:hover { background:green; }
```

you can see an example in: http://jsfiddle.net/3zANs/

Comment: The thing is that the menu is in other elements(like div class="1","2") which are called for other things in the sidebar that aren't menus and different things for different pages. Stripping the padding or margins will create a real mess. I'll take a look and see if I can strip it away for this particular box though.

Comment: It's possible too make the links positioned absoluted, but you have to declare the anchor height, width, left, top, and the height of his parent li for not collapse, for example:[http://jsfiddle.net/3zANs/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/3zANs/8/) use the propper hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

Negative padding is invalid (and simply won't work), negative margin on the other hand is valid and it might be useful in your case.

I believe, also invalid are classes that stars with numbers.

Comment: Ha, figures I used numbers in the example. I don't know why I said negative padding, I know that is irrelevant. I use negative margins all the time though. I can't think of a way to use a negative margin on the link though to get it outside the padding on the surrounding divs.